# Django pagination url parameters

Tags: django

I am trying to use Django's pagination for class based views, as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/).

In my urls.py, I have:

```
url(r'^clues/page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClueIndexView.as_view())
```

The docs tell me I should be able to access this with an url like:

```
/clues/?page=3
```

But that always fails with a 404.

Instead, /clues/page3/ works....but that isn't what I want...I want to use ?page=3.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I'm handling it with a class-based view, like so:

```
class ClueIndexView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'clue_list'
    template_name = 'clue_list.html'
    queryset = Clue.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 10
```

Comment: ANSWERED: The url needed to be just

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
url(r'^clues/$')
def clues(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        page = request.GET.get('page')
...
```

all GET info passed after '?' like your page '?page=n' stored in request.GET dictionary

Comment: Ah, but I would like to use class-based views, as they do in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/).

Answer (score 0):

My url was bad. I found the docs to be a bit confusing. My url needs to be just

```
url(r'^clues/$', views.ClueIndexView.as_view()
```

Works now.